How to solve this isosceles triangle?
In the isosceles triangle ABC, where AB = BC = 5, and BD is perpendicular to AC at D, the angle bisector AO of angle A intersects BD at O. Given that BO = 2 and AO = 4, find the lengths of OD and AC.
Draw line OE through point O perpendicular to AB at point E, then triangle AEO is congruent to triangle ADO.

In the process above, we attempted to use the Pythagorean theorem in the right triangles to find
x and y. However, upon verification, the results do not seem to be correct. Could there be an error in the problem statement or in the calculations?

As you now suspect the problem statement is incorrect, next how would you decide if the suspicion is correct? I might try to find the angles of $\triangle ABO$ (all sides given), and check whether $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle AOD$ are both right.

Let $x$=OD=OE. Then EB=$\sqrt{4-x^2}$ and AE=$\sqrt{16-x^2}$. We have AE+EB=AB, so $$\sqrt{4-x^2}+\sqrt{16-x^2}=5\implies x=\frac{\sqrt{231}}{10}$$
I'll leave the remaining steps to you.
Edit: We also have $AD^2+BD^2=AB^2$, so $$25=(2+x)^2+16-x^2\implies x=\frac{5}{4}$$ Contradiction here.

The answer is also incorrect.

@csn899 What's the correct answer? I think nothing wrong here.

I asked this question because I got multiple answers, and when I checked them, there were errors. Could it be that the question itself is incorrect?

@csn899 Oh, that's right. See my edit.

So, the problem is incorrect.
